# Page in SharePoint hosted app prompting for authentication from ClientWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, iframe, app-part, sharepoint-addin

I have a problem with an .aspx page that I have deployed into the app web of a SharePoint hosted app.

I have a SharePoint site hosted at http://contoso.com for example and have configured my dev environment App settings to host app webs at http://*.contoso.com (I am using a sub domain in dev but will use a completely different domain in prod).

My app gets deployed and everything gets deployed to http://.contoso.com. I also deploy a ClientWebPart that points to the .aspx page hosted in the app web.

My problem is that when I add the ClientWebPart to a page in the Host Web (http://contoso.com) I get an authentication prompt from the app web (http://.contoso.com). Obviously this is because the NTLM credentials isnt being past to the app web as it's on a different domain.

If this was a provider hosted app I could use app only permissions but I just want to keep it simple.

The only alternative is to create a farm solution and host the .aspx page inside the SharePoint farm but this reduces forward compatibility with O365 which I think my client will be moving to shortly (although they have a number of other farm solutions anyway)

Is there a way to have the app web automatically authentication from the host web?